Why does the light on my chandelier rotate when the fan is on high?
This is a chandelier with a fan above the light. After installing, when I turn on the lights and then the fan, and when the fan is on high, the light part beneath the fan doesn’t stay stationary. It slowly rotates and should not. What’s wrong?

Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how to use this site.

I don't see anything in Kpibest's Amazon website or videos indicating the lighting portion is supposed to spin.
I would check the mounting of the fandelier against the ceiling, to be sure the mount and the ceiling junction box are tightly screwed down. Note that a ceiling fan is supposed to have a special fan-compatible junction box in the ceiling, not just a standard junction box.
There could be a possibility of a manufacturing defect, also, and the light kit is not attached firmly.
Don't let the spinning continue. In all likelihood the electrical wiring will get pulled against and fail, possibly spectacularly and fierily.
(One other thing to note, make sure this device has an official authentic safety mark from your country's government on it, like the United States' UL or ETL. Otherwise a fire may not be covered by your insurance company.)
